# Use of !module.parent in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Can you please explain why we are using !module.parent in node. why Node.js Accessing parent modules

```
if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('listening on port 3000');
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I Found answer.
You can use module.parent to determine if the current script is loaded by another script.
Example is here :

a.js:

```
if (!module.parent) {
    console.log("I'm parent");
} else {
    console.log("I'm child");
}
```

b.js:

```
require('./a')
```

run `node a.js` will output:

```
I'm parent
```

run `node b.js` will output:

```
I'm child
```

Comment: What is the implication of this, though? What relevance does it have if it's being run as a child or not?

Comment: Note that ES6 demans `import module from 'module'` for this to work in Node 14+ inside ES modules.

Answer (score 4):

In hierarchical programming paradigms many tasks are done at higher level of hierarchy of a framework, it provides better performance and efficiency. Same is being applied here. If the parent object of running module is not listening to any port, then this task is done by its child object explicitly.

Comment: It' just a check to see if the module is being loaded as a standalone script, instead of having been `require`'d.